# Save data to file .txt - Request Headers , Response Headers and in POST method - Request payload

Tags: python, python-requests

```
pathlib import Path

def saveJSONget(site, code):
    r = requests.get(site)
    json_str = r.text
    if r.status_code != code:
        Path("PATH").write_text(r.text+"\n")
```

I'm trying to save json to file .txt. Do I need to save information about **Request Headers**, **Response Headers** and in POST method - Request payload?

Which function used to save this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is just to handle with OS paths. You should use [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) method to save data in file.

```
if r.status_code != code:
    with open('path/to/file/filename.txt', 'w') as fp;
        fp.write(r.text)
```

The info about requests can be found at **request object**.

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')

>>> r.status_code
200

>>> r.headers
{'Date': 'Fri, 08 Jun 2018 21:14:03 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Vary': 'Cookie', 'Set-Cookie': 'csrftoken=pByJEeBKWtPMrZdpSxzAMpvGod6aqmIf; expires=Fri, 07-Jun-2019 21:14:03 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/', 'Server': 'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.12'}

>>> r.request.headers
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}

>>> r.request.method
'GET'
```

For more info, take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=headers#request-and-response-objects) official doc.

Comment: Ok, but Which function used to save this information? I need to save information about Request Headers, Response Headers and in POST method - Request payload?

Comment: I complemented answer.